# Конвертировать дату в формате timestamp

Tags: javascript, дата

Здравствуйте! Требуется помощь

Написал скрипт на js, который работает с апи slack.com и столкнулся с интересным моментом, когда хотел получить время сообщений (ключ ts)

Формат значения примерно такой **1490647783.975041** и как то из этого нужно вывести только время, например 10ч:00м

Желательно перевести без сторонних библиотек.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то такое?

```js
var a = 1490647783.975041;

var dt = new Date(a);

var hours = dt.getHours();
var minutes = dt.getMinutes();

var resultTime = (hours < 10 ? '0' + hours + 'ч:' : hours + 'ч:') + (minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes + 'м' : minutes + 'м');

console.log(resultTime);
```